# What is the smart way to make a record that can be associated with any object in a hierarchy?

Tags: sql

I am adding a message/email-y feature to my program.  For the most part it is identical in functionality to a very basic email application, it needs a `SENDER`, `RECEIVER`, `MESSAGE`.  Here's the trick now, I also need to be able to associate it with a particular customer, location, area, asset, or project.

In my program already, I have this hierarchy where each project MUST be associated with a asset, each asset MUST be associated with a area, each area MUST be associated with a location and each location MUST have a Customer, however the chain can end at any point for example I can have a Customer with a Location and nothing more.

For reference - `Customer->Location->Area->Asset->Project`.

Each message must be associated with at least a customer but it can be more specific.

Here's my question - how would I go about storing this in the database?
I have two ideas - one is to make a column for each level of association and store the ID when applicable and `NULL` when it is not.

So the table would look like

```
CREATE TABLE messages 
(
    fromUserId int,
    toUserId int,
    message varchar(100),
    customerId int NOT NULL,
    locationId int,
    areaId int,
    assetId int,
    projectId int
)
```

So a message that was associated to a area level would have something like

```
customerId     locationId    areaId    assetId    projectId
=============================================================
1235           4321          5938      NULL       NULL
```

The second idea I had was just record the most specific ID and exactly what it is, like

```
CREATE TABLE messages 
(
    fromUserId int,
    toUserId int,
    message varchar(100),
    parentId int NOT NULL,
    parentObject Varchar
)
```

And the same previous message would be like so

```
parentObject      parentId
===============================
"areaId"          5938
```

Now, I am leaning towards the first way because these messages will also in a table format and filtering on customer, location, area, asset, or project is a feature I have to implement.  The first way makes that very easy, but I feel if this was a large app the extra space taken by the columns is taking up extra space.  Luckily I don't really have to worry about that given how many people use this app (it's a small inhouse thing for inhouse use), but in a different situation seems like this would be less than ideal.

The second way seems to save space but it would also make the filtering queries much more complicated.  If I want to filter by customer, now I have to get every location, area, asset, and project associated with that customer first just to filter properly.

Is there some consensus on how to handle this sort of situation? Is there another third best way?

I am mainly asking because I have seen both methods use elsewhere in my app by other developers. Wondering what your thoughts are SO

Comment: It seems you have 2 entities here: messages and kind of customerDetails.
Each message has its customer ID;
Each customer may or may not have location, area, asset, project.
Personally i would go saving plain data, without hierarchies to keep things simple

Answer (score 0):

Yeah - there's actually a pretty nifty solution to this (assuming I'm not reading the question wrong) - XML.

XML is recommended for when you've got a SQL table column that's going to contain loosely structured or completely unstructured data.  What's really nice is that, if you make your classes serializable, you can just get the Serialization of the class and chuck it into the field; later on, you can slurp that XML back into a .NET object without much fuss.  You can even do cool things like having node indexing on the SQL side to search for elements within the XML (if you so desire.)